# Minimum SSE/AVX version required to compare 2 64-bit integers, atomically?

Tags: intel, sse, simd, avx

Besides the title... is there an easy way to find this information myself? Preferably in a tabular format.

Comment: Why do you think you need SSE/AVX? In 64-bit mode, the general purpose registers are 64 bits wide, so you could do the comparison using standard instructions (like `CMP`).

Comment: Atomically?  I'll just assume you mean "with one instruction".  (Otherwise there are many things you could mean...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy way to find it yourself:

- [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/)

Don't be confused by title; Intrinsics Guide is actually very convinient for the purpose of ISA-specific *instructions* finding.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`pcmpgtq` and `pcmpeqq` were both introduced with SSE4.1, if that's what you're looking for.
x64 with its REX.W CMP has been around for longer though.

See also

- [Intel's manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)
- [AMD's developer guides](http://developer.amd.com/resources/documentation-articles/developer-guides-manuals/)
- [ref.x86asm.net](http://ref.x86asm.net/)

Comment: + `_mm256_blendv_epi8`